# 500 internal server error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I am deploying my ruby 3.2.6 project using passenger 3.0.17 . My httpd.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public
      RackBaseURI /var/www/html/test/public
      <Directory /var/www/html/test/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
      PassengerMinInstances 1
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
RailsSpawnMethod conservative
```

When i deploy my project by starting passenger, it works fine but while uploading images to server, it throws **500 internal error**. I am unable to find the reason for this error and also this error is temporary and is removed after i restart passenger by deleting the cache saved in my ruby project.

I am new to ruby on rails and unable to figure out the reason of this error and why it disappears on restarting passenger.

Please guide me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Apache error log file. If Phusion Passenger does not display an error message in the browser, then it will print the error message to the log file.

Comment: I checked the passenger logs and found issue:  4921#0: *77 open() "/tmp/passenger-standalone.4869/client_body_temp/0000000002" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 122.176.71.55, server: _, request: "POST /uploads/uploadFile HTTP/1.1", host: "test.com", referrer: "http://test/abc/" . When i manually create the folder, issue is removed but reappears after sometime.

Comment: This seems to be the problem. /tmp/passenger-standalone.* must exist because it's used for storing temporary files. Your system probably have some kind of /tmp cleaner which cleans the directory after a while. You should disable it.

Comment: I worked on it but was unable to find any /tmp cleaner. I googled and found this link http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=654 . I am facing the same problem as defined here. Can u plz look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`passenger-status`

If there is an error you probably don't have the gam installed for your ruby version

Use:

`gem install passenger`

Then:

`passenger-install-apache2-module`

Check if passenger running with:

`passenger-memory-stats`

or

`passenger-status`

Follow the instructions on [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu)

You may need to modify `mods-available/passenger.conf` to point to an rbenv or rvm ruby interpreter , not `us/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found out that was having multiple passengers running by checking `passenger-status`. Killed them all then run passenger `passenger start` again on the , NOT the root user.